# Create a small menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hello i need to make a small menu like this [image]
When i press the menu item, differend text is shown.  I am new on wordpress and html. Could somebody explai how to do that ? Maybe there is plugins ?

Comment: why are you putting minuses?

Comment: im compleately new on this, if i would know how to call it i would..

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial from Codex. This guide covers the basic tasks a user may carry out when using the built-in menu editor.

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide

Comment: you understood me wrong. This is not my main menu, its a simple chooser. You choose a header of a text, and click it. Then you see thext of that header